# When CloudFront is activated some elements are failing to load

Tags: wordpress, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I use WordPress and I'm using CloudFront as my content delivery network. When activating CloudFront some elements, practically icons are not loading, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This code (in .htaccess) resolved the problem

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the cache from your CloudFront Dashboard.

CloudFront captures all your webpages as a cached to increase page loading speed.

I think you are facing this problem for new pages or posts.